# Download video file from youtube to internal storage

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have a youtube video link, like this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCysW3PCzvo
I want to get list of video source urls (for diffrent qualities). I have this method in php. How i can do that trick in android?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vget is a Java library to download videos from YouTube or Vimeo, or get the actual URLs to the video file. Check it out on GitHub:

**https://github.com/axet/vget**

It's pure Java, so will work on Android.

Comment: thx, have you tried this by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have used it, on desktop Java though, quite a while ago. I haven't used it on Android, but it works well, @HankMoody

Comment: This GITHUB link you've provided above is no more there. Error 404.

Comment: There's a fork / copy of it available here: https://github.com/laserjim/vget, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Code for 1440: vq=hd1440
Code for 1080: vq=hd1080
Code for 720: vq=hd720
Code for 480p: vq=large
Code for 360p: vq=medium
Code for 240p: vq=small

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCysW3PCzvo&vq=hd1440

This may only work for embedded, I've not tested
https://www.youtube.com/embed/UCysW3PCzvo?vq=hd1080

Comment: thx for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am find source which helps me get source url
https://github.com/flipstudio/YouTubeExtractor